# Drag image within it's parent

Tags: c#, wpf, imaging

So, I'm using this approach to be able to drag an image:

[Dragging an image in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294220/dragging-an-image-in-wpf)

And works great but the problem is it depends on a canvas but it draws and drag the image outside the canvas. This is the extender I'm using, is it possible to limit itself to just the original canvas size.

What I want to do is to be able to (within the original canvas size) drag the image to see parts that at the beginning are not visible.

**Extender**

```
public class DraggableExtender : DependencyObject
    {
        // This is the dependency property we're exposing - we'll 
        // access this as DraggableExtender.CanDrag="true"/"false"
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CanDragProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CanDrag",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(DraggableExtender),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnChangeCanDragProperty));

        // The expected static setter
        public static void SetCanDrag(UIElement element, bool o)
        {
            element.SetValue(CanDragProperty, o);
        }

        // the expected static getter
        public static bool GetCanDrag(UIElement element)
        {
            return (bool)element.GetValue(CanDragProperty);
        }

        // This is triggered when the CanDrag property is set. We'll
        // simply check the element is a UI element and that it is
        // within a canvas. If it is, we'll hook into the mouse events
        private static void OnChangeCanDragProperty(DependencyObject d,
                  DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UIElement element = d as UIElement;
            if (element == null) return;

            if (e.NewValue != e.OldValue)
            {
                if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                {
                    element.PreviewMouseDown += element_PreviewMouseDown;
                    element.PreviewMouseUp += element_PreviewMouseUp;
                    element.PreviewMouseMove += element_PreviewMouseMove;
                }
                else
                {
                    element.PreviewMouseDown -= element_PreviewMouseDown;
                    element.PreviewMouseUp -= element_PreviewMouseUp;
                    element.PreviewMouseMove -= element_PreviewMouseMove;
                }
            }
        }

        // Determine if we're presently dragging
        private static bool _isDragging = false;
        // The offset from the top, left of the item being dragged 
        // and the original mouse down
        private static Point _offset;

        // This is triggered when the mouse button is pressed 
        // on the element being hooked
        static void element_PreviewMouseDown(object sender,
                System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // Ensure it's a framework element as we'll need to 
            // get access to the visual tree
            FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
            if (element == null) return;

            // start dragging and get the offset of the mouse 
            // relative to the element
            _isDragging = true;
            _offset = e.GetPosition(element);
        }

        // This is triggered when the mouse is moved over the element
        private static void element_PreviewMouseMove(object sender,
                  MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // If we're not dragging, don't bother - also validate the element
            if (!_isDragging) return;

            FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
            if (element == null) return;

            Canvas canvas = element.Parent as Canvas;
            if (canvas == null) return;

            // Get the position of the mouse relative to the canvas
            Point mousePoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);

            // Offset the mouse position by the original offset position
            mousePoint.Offset(-_offset.X, -_offset.Y);

            // Move the element on the canvas
            element.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, mousePoint.X);
            element.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, mousePoint.Y);
        }

        // this is triggered when the mouse is released
        private static void element_PreviewMouseUp(object sender,
                MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _isDragging = false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am complete off base here, but I think the problem is in the XAML of your Canvas and not in your Extender.

Do you have the ClipToBounds="True" property set on your Canvas because it defaults to false on a Canvas object.

```
<Canvas ClipToBounds="True" />
```

Comment: Rhyous you're the boss! thanks bro! actually, that was the problem.