# How to create high speed virtual mouse cursor?

Tags: .net, wpf, performance

How would a framework element get moved and behave as a cursor in real time ?
For example, if I added an event listener for mouse move, and moved an image than presents the virtual cursor, the moved image will be noticed as following the mouse.

Our app will have more than moving cursor.
Whats' the most efficient way to move a cursor size image inside a window ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom cursor in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805/custom-cursor-in-wpf)

Comment: You just place it on the canvas with and x y position.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294220/dragging-an-image-in-wpf ?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from creating a custom cursor, instead of simulating it?

Comment: I think he wants an image that follows the mouse cursor not replace it.

Comment: I need to simulate a custom cursor instead of creating one because I need two cursors at the same time, yet placing an image at a canvas an moving it with x & y won't be as speedy as a custom cursor ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Cursor x = new Cursor("yourCursorPath");
this.Cursor = x;
```

Comment: I need a custom cursor solution as I will be moving two cursors at the same time ..