# Add a custom local property to a control?

Tags: c#, wpf, draggable

I've found this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/294412/8673248) which allows dragging a control around a canvas.

What is the way to add this draggable property programmatically to a control that's created in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it like this, for example:

```
Button b = new Button();

b.SetValue(DraggableExtender.CanDragProperty, true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This was exactly it.